# Does $f'(x) \geq \frac{f(x)}{x}$ imply $f''(x) \geq 0$ on the positive reals if $f(0)\geq 0$

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

I was looking at [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3008434/prove-that-fx-frac-fxx-for-a-continuous-differentiable-fx) and I was wondering if a variation of the inverse statement is also true.

That is, given a function $f$ twice differentiable with $f(0)\geq 0$ and $f'(x) \geq \frac{f(x)}{x}$ will $f''(x)\geq 0$ (working on the domain $[0,\infty)$)?

I couldn't immediately see a way to prove it or find an easy counter example so if anyone has any hints or tips that would be appreciated.

Comment: What is the domain of $f$? I guess you want it to be $[0, \infty)$ with the inequality holding on $(0, \infty)$. (The linked question seems to have $[0, 1]$ as domain.)

Comment: Yes sorry I forgot to include that I was working on $[0,\infty)$ not $[0,1]$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align}  
f''(x) &= \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f'(x+h) - f'(x)}{h} \\  
       & \geq \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\frac{f(x+h)}{x+h} - f'(x)}{h} \\
       &= \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x+h) - xf'(x)}{h(x+h)} - \frac{f'(x)}{x+h} = -\frac{f'(x)}{x} + \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x+h) - xf'(x)}{h(x+h)}
\end{align}

Now, we will find the limit:

$$\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x+h) - xf'(x)}{h(x+h)} $$

because $f'(x) \geq \frac{f(x)}{x}$ then $-f(x) \geq -xf'(x)$. Therefore:

$$ \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x+h) - xf'(x)}{h(x+h)} \geq \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x+h) - f(x)}{h(x+h)} = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x+h) - f(x)}{h} \times \frac{1}{x+h} = \frac{f'(x)}{x}$$

finally, we get that

$$ f''(x) \geq \frac{f'(x)}{x} - \frac{f'(x)}{x} = 0$$

as we wanted.